# Is there any way I can use same blob container for all the Assets output I create in Azure Media Service?

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I am processing video in azure media service for streaming option from blob container of same storage account by passing blob url. But when ever I process any video with new asset a new container is added under Blob containers and I need to do this for large number of videos on daily basis. So is there a way to use single container for all output asset generate OR is there any other option I can directly stream blob video without using media service ? Also I am using H265SingleBitrate720p for video encode as I want only single resolution video to be generated but is there way I can generate single encode video with same resolution, framerate and bitrate as input asset linked videolike AdaptiveStreming Preset but single file.

I have read some where using sub directories in container but not sure if it is possible and best practice or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a duplicate post of the one on the Microsoft Q&A site here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/527588/is-there-any-way-i-can-use-same-container-for-all.html

Take a look at the detailed response over there first.

Comment: Yes, sorry for duplicate post. due to impatient nature I also put same question on stackoverflow. but now I am looking for other options as it seems with multiple files in same container it will become unmanageable in getting separate streaming endpoint for each file on each request. now looking for something like generating streaming point for existing files on blob without media service or transform.